# Angular Directive - replaceWith, ng-repeat and destroy

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ondestroy, replacewith

I have an array that is used for an `ng-repeat`. When this is updated, the directive is not currently not removed / destroyed from the DOM.

The `link` function in the directive does a `replaceWith` replacing the element with a custom compiled element. `Append()` worked fine with `destroy` but it messed up the layout. So I would like to keep the `replaceWith` if possible.

In the directive I have the following:

```
element.replaceWith( customElement );
```

The element is passed via the link function and the customElement is a newly compiled element using the same scope passed via link.

The on `destroy` event is triggered correctly. However, I have no way of removing the customElement from the DOM. I have tried `empty()`. `remove()` and nothing works.

Anyone have any ideas? I can give more info if require.

Comment: Please add js for this

Comment: Provide code for this.